# Meaning of "fools of men"

Tags: meaning

I am analyzing a text and have come upon this sentence:

> For these fools of men and their woes care not thou at all! [1](http://lib.oto-usa.org/libri/liber0220.html#chap1)

I suspect there is something interesting about this construction, "fools of men". I searched the OED for something like this under «fool» and «man» with no luck.

Searching Google, I found other ocurrences which appear to mean the same thing.

> Girls are laid under an apparent restraint by their mothers, in hopes that their outward carriage will deceive poor fools of men, and be the means of procuring them a husband. [2](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=wNVCAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=%22fools+of+men%22+-%22make+fools%22+-%22makes+fools%22+-%22made+fools%22&source=bl&ots=QQBhUlC36P&sig=j61D59GtUtvs5Lz-xb25CR8oSfU&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir8JivuNnVAhWDhpAKHXUbBd4Q6AEIUzAG#v=onepage&q=%22fools%20of%20men%22%20-%22make%20fools%22%20-%22makes%20fools%22%20-%22made%20fools%22&f=false)

.

> And then
>   I said we ought to be off and show a clean pair of heels. But my
>   fools of men refused. [3](https://archive.org/stream/TheOdyssey/TXT/00000135.txt)

What is the meaning of "fools of men"?

Comment: Look up the word **of** in some decent online dictionaries (Oxford, Websters, American Heritage, MacMillan) and see what they say.

Comment: *care not thou* is ungrammatical. Are you sure you’ve transcribed it properly?

Comment: @Jim I'm sure. This text is a little strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fools of men* means *men who are fools* or *foolish men*

Answer (score -1):

There also seems to be a hint of 'foolish *examples* of men" to this phrase. If the rest of the context is very judgmental, the phrase could also convey something along the lines of "a sorry excuse of a man."